# Importing a large CSV into Wordpress with CSV Importer plugin

Tags: csv, phpmyadmin, wordpress, import-from-csv

I'm trying to import a rather large csv file (90mb, 255,000 records) into wordpress using the CSV Importer plugin.

I realize this plugin wasn't made for this large of files, but I can't seem to figure out any other option here. Using phpmyadmin will only let me import certain things such as the post title, etc... I also need to add some postmeta along with each post in the csv.

I've tried everything I can think of, from uploading the file to my server via ftp, and then editing the plugin to read the local file (just stops working)... I've changed the php max execution time, I've change the maximum file size, all to no avail.

Any help is appreciated here.

Comment: can you share how you edited to read the local file?  I may try with some other plugin

Answer (score 0):

Aside from breaking the CSV file into multiple parts, try importing the data yourself, with your own custom PHP script.

See wp_insert_post() documentation, and of course, PHP's fgetcsv().